# dead lettering in Azure event grid does not work

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid, azure-web-pubsub

As per the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry#retry-schedule), Event Grid does not implement retry on specific errors like 400, 413, 401. In such cases Event Grid will either perform dead-lettering on the event or drop the event if dead-letter isn't configured.

So I enabled dead letter on my webhook (receiver endpoint) and produced a 400 error. But it is still not captured in dead letter logs container.
Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the [Event Grid message delivery and retry - Dead-letter events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry#dead-letter-events) documentation and see if your configuration is correct.

> By default, Event Grid doesn't turn on dead-lettering. To enable it, you must specify a storage account to hold undelivered events when creating the event subscription. You pull events from this storage account to resolve deliveries.
>
> [...]
>
> Before setting the dead-letter location, you must have a storage account with a container. You provide the endpoint for this container when creating the event subscription. The endpoint is in the format of: `/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-name>/blobServices/default/containers/<container-name>`

Also, take into account that

> There's a five-minute delay between the last attempt to deliver an event and when it's delivered to the dead-letter location. This delay is intended to reduce the number of Blob storage operations. If the dead-letter location is unavailable for four hours, the event is dropped.